# How to compile assembly code in Visual Studios?

Tags: c++

I can't get the following assembly code to compile in Visual Studio 2010:

```
asm( "mov $950706376,%%ecx  \n\t"
     "mul %%ecx             \n\t"
     "mov $2147483647,%%ecx \n\t"
     "div %%ecx                 "
     : "=d" (rn_seed) : "a" (rn_seed) : "%ecx" );
```

I get the following error message:  syntax error : missing ')' before ':'

Does anyone know to make it compile?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a syntax issue. Please edit your question and include the error messages you get, they're kind of important.

Comment: @aldanux:  Thanks for improving the format.  How did you do the line break after ". . . Visual Studio 2010:"?  I tried doing the double-space, like it said in the Markdown Help, but it didn't work. Sorry, put I'm pretty new to StackOverflow.

Comment: @SpeedPacer - double enter :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for Inline Assembler in the Microsoft compiler is different than this one you are using.

Take a look at this document about **Inline Assembler**:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know what compiler the above syntax is for?

Comment: Most notable statement on the *Inline Assembler* MSDN page: *"Inline assembly is not supported on the ARM and x64 processors."*

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
__asm
{
    mov 0x950706376, ecx;
    mul ecx;
    mov 0x2147483647, ecx;
    div ecx;
}
```

Comment: You've got the arguments in reverse order: Intel syntax has the destination on the left while the AT&T syntax (as used in the question) puts it on the right. The first instruction should read `mov ecx, 0x950706376` instead.